# My texts in the <p> tag after the header is squeezing into the header. How should i change that?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a web page using css. For some reason my header does not spread over where the header should be, which means the width is not 100%. it looks like this now [this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g57c2.jpg)

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
}
#logo_picture {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
#logo img,
#logo nav {
  float: left;
}
#logo nav {
  line-height: 120px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Arsenal', 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 2px 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a,
nav a:visited {
  color: black;
}
nav a.selected,
nav a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Larry Rosenburg Official Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Crimson+Text:400,700,700i|Rakkas" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Swash|Cinzel|Gentium+Basic|Muli" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="lincoln.jpg" width="30%" alt="Lincoln logo" id="logo_picture">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="http://www.lincolnlandservices.com/index.html"> Lincoln </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
          </li>
          <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>

  <h1> Larry Rosenburg </h1> 
  <p>
    I believe that as important as skills and experiences are in our professional careers, it is the relationships that we create which allow us to truly succeed. My company provides title insurance, settlement, escrow and exchange services on a level that
    is second to none, but my focus is helping your succeed with your commercial and residential transactions. As a person who can deliver a full range of solutions, I am able to leverage the power of my company with my drive to be concerned with your
    company.
  </p>

  <div id="profile-pic">
    <img src="picture.jpg" width="35%" alt="">
  </div>


</body>

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: set body width 100%

Comment: Probably this is *not* the cause for your problems, but you are closing the `<body>` BEFORE the footer, which isn't good. Move the `</body>` tag down below `</footer>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After every float you must create a clear class. Try adding in the CSS:

```
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

in the html after the `</header>` add `<div class="clearfix">`

Comment: hey Fares! it worked! Thank you so much! But for some reason I couldn't adjust the margin-top of h1, it seems to be connected to the header. How should I fix that?

Comment: You didn't specify any rules in your CSS for the h1. Try adding in your html a class for your h1 something like `<h1 class="title">text here</h1>`
in your css add:
`.title {margin-top 20px;}`